# Trouble importing java bcrypt library

Tags: java, spring-boot, bcrypt

I faced a problem with importing the Spring Security library.

Here is my main class:

```
package com.example.test.myfirstproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyFirstProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyFirstProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfirstproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myfirstproject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I'm trying to make a build in IntelliJ IDEA I get errors:

```
java: package org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt does not exist

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BCryptPasswordEncoder
  location: class com.example.test.myfirstproject.MyFirstProjectApplication
```

I used autocomplete for method BCryptPasswordEncoder, so there shouldn't be a mistake. I also tried to change the place of security dependency in pom.xml file, but it also didn't help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like a dependency issue...I just generated a new IDEA spring boot project and brought in `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and built/ran successfully. My POM is a little different from yours and brought this dependency in: `<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId><artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId><version>5.4.5</version></dependency>`

Comment: @ZackMacomber the `org.springframework.security:spring-security-core` is already part of the dependency list posted above ...

Comment: What happens if you take the version off of the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency? I'm able to run my app without the version specified.

Comment: @ZackMacomber it doesnt help( I still see "crypto" marked red in line "import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;" in my main class file and the system says "Cannot resolve symbol 'crypto'"

Comment: Does changing your project version to `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` make any difference?

Comment: @ZackMacomber no, I still get an error regarding my main class

Comment: I brought your dependencies into my pom and noticed I needed a version for `io.jsonwebtoken`. I put in `0.9.1`. Does it help to put a version on that dependency?

Comment: @ZackMacomber I also did this and it still doesn't help. I don't know what else to try

Comment: Did you checked if the dependecy have been properly downloaded? `ls ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/ `

Comment: @mrak I don't have any notifications regarding errors with installing dependencies, looks like everything is installed correctly

Comment: Sometimes it helps to start from scratch with a clean / working project and add things carefully one by one. You could also remove things until your project compiles and then add stuff back little by little. It's painful but sometimes it's what you have to do to get something working.

Comment: @ZackMacomber well, I solved the problem... There was somekind of problem with Maven, I reloaded the project two times in Idea and problem is gone

Comment: Good to hear. Sometimes running File -> Invalidate Caches can help clean up a project and make it run right too.